# Ruby commands conflicting with program in $gopath

Tags: ruby, go, rbenv

I had rbenv installed (with homebrew) and working on my mac with several versions of ruby in the past. For a period of time I didn't use Ruby very much and have installed other things (including  OSX 10.9.3 and Go) on my computer. I ran rbenv today and it repeated this message over and over

```
tory
/usr/local/bin/rbenv: line 14: cd: Usage:  Head host:port: No such file or directory
/usr/local/bin/rbenv: line 14: cd: Usage:  Head host:port: No such file or directory
/usr/local/bin/rbenv: line 14: cd: Usage:  Head host:port: No such file or directory
/usr/local/bin/rbenv: line 14: cd: Usage:  Head host:port: No such file or directory
^C
```

When I run `ruby -v` it repeats this message over and over

```
/usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/0.4.0/libexec/rbenv: line 14: cd: Usage:  Head host:port: No such file or directory
/usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/0.4.0
```

I uninstalled rbenv with homebrew and reinstalled it but have the same problem.

When I run `jekyll serve -w` (to run a jekyll blog locally), I also get the error

```
/usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/0.4.0/libexec/rbenv: line 14: cd: Usage:  Head host:port: No such file or directory
```

Update
I have recently installed Go on my computer and ran a few Go programs today, one of which is called `Head`. It appears the error message that I'm getting when trying to run rbenv or jekyll is from one of the Go scripts in my $GOPATH. This is the HEAD script, which is printing the error message

```
"Usage: ", os.Args[0], "host:port"
```

This program is located in the $GOPATH

```
/Users/randomname/go/src/github.com/myname/head
```

I don't see why that would conflict with Ruby commands

```
/* Head
 */

package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    if len(os.Args) != 2 {
        fmt.Println("Usage: ", os.Args[0], "host:port")
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    url := os.Args[1]

    response, err := http.Head(url)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
        os.Exit(2)
    }

    fmt.Println(response.Status)
    for k, v := range response.Header {
        fmt.Println(k+":", v)
    }

    os.Exit(0)
}
```

this is my bash_profile. Question: Is there something in this file that's causing the conflict?

```
### Added by the Heroku Toolbelt
export PATH="/usr/local/heroku/bin:$PATH"

export PGHOST=localhost


export LASTFM_API='76479e879457be34dd1180f78e731fc0'

export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/mysql/bin
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"

export GOPATH=/Users/randomname/go/
export PATH=$GOPATH/bin:$PATH

# The next line updates PATH for the Google Cloud SDK.
source '/Users/my_name/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc'

# The next line enables bash completion for gcloud.
source '/Users/randomname/google-cloud-sdk/completion.bash.inc'

alias goapp=~/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/goapp

export PATH=/path/to/go_appengine:$PATH
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's trying to use GNU `head` and it's catching your version, which is a completely different program, you will have to change the name to something else and delete `$GOPATH/bin/head`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this [issue](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv/issues/389) has to do something with yours. The issue is fixed [here](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv/commit/81bb14e181c556e599e20ca6fdc86fdb690b8995) but have not been released yet. The commit message suggests that your may have not GNU coreutils installed, so perhaps you may want to install it using

```
brew install coreutils
```

But I'm not an OSX user so I can't be sure that this would fix it.